# Prior art for the same exists

Tags: prior-art

In reference to the patent: [US20130321393](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130321393)

Please note Prior Art - http://www.google.com/patents/US8705110

Comment: I didn't read the documents, but don't assume one invalidates the other just because the titles are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the claims of either application/patent are covered by the disclosure of the other, but please note that the application corresponding to US 2013/0321393 A1 actually has an earlier priority date than any document corresponding to US 8705110 B2.